# How to find out Client's private ip in React or Node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ip

## Problem

Currently I need to compare the user's private ip with the ip of the certificate.

Is there a way to find out the user's private ip in react or node?

## I tried

I got a public ip but not a private ip

```
/* in React.js */
    const getIP = async () => {
        const res = await axios.get('https://geolocation-db.com/json/');
        console.log("getIP : ",res.data);
        setCurrentIP(res.data.IPv4);
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        getIP();
    },[]);
```

Comment: What do you mean by private IP?

Comment: A public IP has a unique IP address in the world.

A private IP is an IP address of a network assigned to a general home or company, and is also called a local IP or virtual IP.

Comment: There is no such thing. What you refer to as a "private IP" are what we call public IPs. Private/local IPs are a different system used for LAN communication.

Comment: ref :
https://www.avast.com/c-ip-address-public-vs-private
https://www.slingbox.com/help/kb/KB-2000143

public ip like external ip and private ip like internal ip

Comment: I understand what you're asking (you want the 192.168.x.x or 10.x.x.x or whatever IP address the private network uses internally and which the router translates using Network Address Translation [NAT]), but routers aren't supposed to leak this information. If you do get it somehow, you're being unethical. Visit ipleak.net for more information

Comment: @barrycarter it's not really any sort of sensitive information, it's just how we organize LAN communication. It has no meaning outside the network.

Comment: @Kite_Z What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @skara9 When a user uploads a certificate, we need to compare the subject IP of the certificate and the current user's IP to see if it is the same.

Comment: @Kite_Z What kind of certificate are you referring to?

Comment: @skara9 SSL Certificate https://www.cloudflare.com/ko-kr/learning/ssl/what-is-an-ssl-certificate/

Comment: @Kite_Z So you're saying you have a local network with devices that you have issued SSL certificates for on private IPs? You can't validate something like that from outside the network.

Comment: @skara9 
So I decided to get the private ip input from the user.

Comment: @skara9 You appear to be correct. I was told it was bad and should be avoided, but https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4824/how-bad-is-the-leaking-of-internal-ip-addresses-through-external-dns suggests the risk is minimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 ->

Any IP address of your machine you can find by using the os module - and that's native to Node.js:

```
const os = require('os');

const networkInterfaces = os.networkInterfaces();
const ip = networkInterfaces['eth0'][0]['address']

console.log(networkInterfaces);
```

Option 2 ->

You might like to use npm package
[npm install internal-ip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/internal-ip)

```
import {internalIpV6, internalIpV4} from 'internal-ip';

console.log(await internalIpV6());
//=> 'fe80::1'

console.log(await internalIpV4());
//=> '10.0.0.79'
```

AND FOR REFERENCE FINS THE LINK BELOW. HOPE IT HELPS

Option 3 ->
[YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TID8Z29je5o)

[Web App to check IP](https://react-component-depot.netlify.app/find-my-ip)

[GitHub Source Code](https://github.com/codegeous/react-component-depot/blob/master/src/pages/GeoLocation/index.js)

Some additional read you might like ->

For React.js ->
[Find Client's IP Address in React.js](https://www.thetechplatform.com/post/how-to-get-user-ip-address-in-react-js)

For Node.js ->
[Client's IP Address in Node.js](https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-get-the-ip-address-of-a-client-in-nodejs)

Comment: The networkInterfaces() function is not supported on Windows. Is there any other way?

Comment: and [ For React.js -> Find Client's IP Address in React.js ] is get public ip 
, I want user's internal(private) ip

Comment: @Kite_Z will this help? If you want anything else feel free to ask. I will respond

Comment: I already tried it. The result is undefined. I read the API description, but I couldn't solve it.

Comment: @Kite_Z check option 3 mate, if even this does not work, then I think you need to talk to an expert regarding it

Comment: I think the first two options require running node.js on the internal machine, and the third option gives the external IP address? Am I missing something?